# Threading: How to interrupt run-Method if run does not use a while-loop Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I implemented (in Python 3.5) a two Player board game (named Othello) which uses different bots. The simplest bot would choose the next step randomly, but the computation time of the hardest bot could take minutes, but if it takes too long, the computation should be interrupted and the best current choice should be taken. So, after a given Timeout (say 3 seconds), the bot computation should be interupted. The main-loop looks roughly like this:

```
bot_black = my_random_bot("black")
bot_white = my_random_bot("white")

while not one_has_won:
    if player == 0:
        bot_black.pos_positions = self.possible_positions(player)
        bot_black.start()
        bot_black.join(3)
        idy, idx = bot_black.cur_choice

    else:
        bot_white.pos_positions = self.possible_positions(player)
        bot_white.start()
        bot_white.join(3)
        idy, idx = bot_white.cur_choice
```

Where `bot_black` and `bot_white` are instances of the class Random_Bot which looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import threading
import time

class Random_Bot(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, color):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.color = color
        self.pos_positions = None
        self.cur_choice = None

    def run(self):
        pos_p = [(idr, idz) for idr, row in enumerate(self.pos_positions) for ide, elem in enumerate(row) if elem == "pos_p"]
        self.cur_choice = pos_p[0]

        wait_time = np.random.randint(0, 3)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        random_elem = np.random.randint(0, len(pos_p))
        result = pos_p[random_elem]
        self.cur_choice = result
```

In order to test the interruption I use a Random Variable between 0 and 2 which is used for the sleep-function.

If I run this, I get the Error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 840, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

I could handle this problem, by taking a new instance of the bots in each iteration of the main loop, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. That would look like this:

```
while not one_has_won:
    bot_black = my_random_bot("black")
    bot_white = my_random_bot("white")
    if player == 0:
        bot_black.pos_positions = self.possible_positions(player)
        bot_black.start()
        bot_black.join(3)
        idy, idx = bot_black.cur_choice

    else:
        bot_white.pos_positions = self.possible_positions(player)
        bot_white.start()
        bot_white.join(3)
        idy, idx = bot_white.cur_choice
```

If I do this, it seems like the old Thread is not running anymore (by just looking to the Windows Task-Manager), but maybe the computation is too weak?. Is there a better way to avoid this Exception or is it the wrong way to uses Threads?

Comment: You really don't want `Random_Bot` to **be** a thread itself, you want it to *use* a thread.. the way your code is written right now, `Random_Bot` is a thread and you're attempting to start said thread/random bot every iteration of your `while` loop, which is not possible. The random bots presumably run on their own thread? If that is the case the types you are using are not set up properly for this application.

Comment: Yes, I know that Random_Bot is a subclass from the class Thread, but why is that a problem? The idea comes from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm) see second example.

Comment: Well.. a thread runs its operation **once** you're attempting to have `Random_Bot` `run`/`start` every iteration of the loop. **A Thread is not meant to run more than once. You cannot run or start the thread every iteration of a loop**. You do not need `Random_Bot` to **-be-** a thread, you (presumably) need it to **run** on its own thread (as I assume, you want both bots running at the same time yes? a thread for each bot). Right now you're treating the Random Bot as if it **is** the thread, and that is a problem.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I do not need to run the bots at the same time. A simple timeout for the first bot would be enough for me. Do you have any suggestions about how I can do this? Is the threading package good for this?

Comment: Threading is for running two operations at once. If the bots can take turns you don't need threads at all. I would highly recommend looking at a better example than the one you showed. The example you showed specifically talks about subclassing threads which is something I'm almost positive you will **never** have to do (what application level functionality would be useful to add to such a low-level abstraction..? Nothing, so there's no reason to subclass) Check out an example like [this](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/) for threads

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed it and it looks a lot cleaner. Now I have a new similar problem. If player "black" needs longer than the maximum allowed computation time, then the main thread continues and player "white" starts. Is there a way to interupt the player after the timeout? Now I used `time.sleep(1)` in the main loop for the max computation time.

Comment: It never makes any sense to `join()` a thread immediately after starting it. The entire point of threads is that they can do things _concurrently_. The correct way to use threads is, (1) start a new thread, (2) _do something else concurrently with the new thread,_ and then optionally, (3) join the thread.

Comment: Re, "I do not need to run the bots at the same time." Don't _need_ to, true. But human players don't just go to sleep when it's their opponent's turn. A more sophisticated bot could run continuously, exploring and evaluating possible future moves, even during the opponent's turn.

Comment: Yes, I know that. In (2) I only want to wait few seconds.

Comment: @Brayn, OK, I was just going by what is actually shown in your code example: (e.g., `bot_black.start()` immediately followed by `bot_black.join()`.

Comment: thanks for asking that. According to the documentation and the link which was shared by @user1538301 the parameter of join corresponds to timeout. So actually I'm just waiting for this timeout. But due to my print statements, I know the Thread is still working